# Why would Paperclip be failing to find the geometry key when on my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm getting an error in thumbnail.rb saying :geometry is empty

Here's a condensed version of the stack:

```
NoMethodError in PagesController#create

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

RAILS_ROOT: ...
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

.../vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb:18:in `initialize'
.../vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/processor.rb:33:in `new'
.../vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/processor.rb:33:in `make'
.../vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:295:in `post_process_styles'
.../usr/lib/ruby/1.8/erb.rb:719:in `inject'
....
```

The thing I find to be rather weird is that it works fine on my local machine, and not sporadically on my server.

My has_attached_file looks like so:

```
  has_attached_file :foreground,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
                    :bucket => 'recurse',
                    :path => ":attachment/:id_partition/:token/:style/:filename",
                    :styles => {
                      :medium => {:geometry => '372x251>'},
                      :small => {:geometry => '188x156>'},
                      :original_strip => {:geometry => '100x100%', :processors => [:Cropper]},
                      :medium_strip => {:geometry => '100x100%', :processors => [:MediumCropper]},
                      :small_strip => {:geometry => '100x100%', :processors => [:SmallCropper]},
                    }

  has_attached_file :background,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/amazon_s3.yml",
                    :bucket => 'recurse',
                    :path => ":attachment/:id_partition/:token/:style/:filename",
                    :styles => {
                      :medium => {:geometry => '372x251>'},
                      :small => {:geometry => '188x156>'}
                    }
```

And thumbnail.rb:18 has @crop on it...

```
  geometry             = options[:geometry]
  @file                = file
  @crop                = geometry[-1,1] == '#'
  @target_geometry     = Geometry.parse geometry
  @current_geometry    = Geometry.from_file @file
```

Any help would be immensely useful, as I haven't been able to find anything that fixes this on google. [Here's a github issue](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issuesearch?state=open&q=undefined+method#issue/259) as well, if you care to reply there instead/as

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't even noticed it until just now.

Answer (score 0):

Style.rb lines 18-21 need to be:

```
    @geometry = definition[:geometry]
    @format = definition[:format]
    @processors = definition[:processors]
    @other_args = definition.reject {|key,value|[:geometry, :format, :processors].include?(key)}
```

http://groups.google.com/group/paperclip-plugin/browse_thread/thread/c2f5a7ae58fff976

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears to be fixed in 2.3.4.

Here's the relevant change:

```
@@ -55,7 +57,7 @@
       unless @normalized_styles
         @normalized_styles = {}
         (@styles.respond_to?(:call) ? @styles.call(self) : @styles).each do |name, args|
-          @normalized_styles[name] = Paperclip::Style.new(name, args, self)
+          @normalized_styles[name] = Paperclip::Style.new(name, args.dup, self)
         end
       end
       @normalized_styles
```

Here's what I think is happening prior to 2.3.4 and why this change solves the problem:

In development, class caching is typically disabled, while in production it is not. Note that the only change above is `args` -> `args.dup`. `Style#initialize`, by using `Hash#delete`, was modifying the original args for a style, not a copy. The first image processed got all of the args, while later images did not because `Style#initialize` had removed the key from the options Hash.

The link to the Google Group posting also fixed the problem because instead of modifying the original Hash, it uses `Hash#reject`, which returns a copy of the Hash with the keys removed. It solves the problem in essentially the same way, but with a larger change to the code.